# Using DECODE on a parameter in WHERE clause will shortcircuit using the index?

Tags: oracle, performance, stored-procedures, oracle11g

I have a stored procedure with multiple mandatory parameters and a `SELECT` statement inside it which has multiple conditions in its `WHERE` clause, like below:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE column_1 = param_1
   AND column_2 = param_2
   AND column_3 = param_3;
```

This query works fine and it uses the indexes on the table correctly. But a change in requirements implied adjusting the procedure so that you can pass it less parameters, so maybe just the first two, but we want the procedure to work with minimal changes to the stored procedure.

One of the suggestions I've made was to use a `DECODE` function to treat each possibly `NULL` parameter, like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE column_1 = param_1
   AND column_2 = param_2
   AND column_3 = DECODE(param_3, null, column_3);
```

And this way, I considered that because the function is not applied on the table column, the index will still be used. I have made some tests and the query still works and uses the indexes even in this situation.

But I'm still getting contradicted by our architect (with no other explanations), that the query will not use the index because I'm using a function in the `WHERE` clause.

I'm not sure if my change is enough proof that it will **always** use the index, or if there are other situations which I should check and in which the index might *not* be used because of the `DECODE` function.

Any help / suggestions / information will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Your interpretation is correct. The architect needs to justify what they are saying. If they are really claiming that using *any* function *anywhere* in the `where` clause prevents an index being used, you could point out that [`sysdate` is a function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions191.htm), for example. Although Oracle treats it as a special case sometimes. (Not relevant, but your decode could be replaced with `NVL(param_3, column_3)`; or you could use `(parm_3 IS NULL OR column_3 = param_3)` or similar).

Comment: @AlexPoole Thank you! Makes sense and actually it fits perfectly, because one of our other conditions in the `WHERE` clause is `sysdate`.

Comment: Always is very strong word for DB. I would rather say "it depends" or mostly.

Comment: @AlexPoole I've tested both `NVL` and `DECODE` and it seems that `DECODE` estimates the cardinality better and has a slightly better cost than `NVL`.

Comment: @lad2025 I was actually meaning to say "always use the index in this scenario", but I'm guessing where a full-table-scan is better, then it will use a full-table-scan. But this is not the case and we're not aggregating records or anything "heavy-duty".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right. Test it and prove it.

**Setup**

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE t AS SELECT LEVEL id FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <=10;

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> CREATE INDEX id_indx ON t(ID);

Index created.
```

**Test case**

Normal query, without any function:

```
SQL> set autot on explain
SQL>
SQL> SELECT * FROM t  WHERE ID = 5;

        ID
----------
         5


Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1629656632

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation        | Name    | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT |         |     1 |     3 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  INDEX RANGE SCAN| ID_INDX |     1 |     3 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - access("ID"=5)
```

Using **DECODE** on the value(**not on column**):

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM t  WHERE ID = decode(5, NULL, 3, 5);

        ID
----------
         5


Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1629656632

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation        | Name    | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT |         |     1 |     3 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  INDEX RANGE SCAN| ID_INDX |     1 |     3 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - access("ID"=5)
```

Using **NVL** on the value(**not on column**):

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM t  WHERE ID = nvl(5, 3);

        ID
----------
         5


Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1629656632

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation        | Name    | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT |         |     1 |     3 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  INDEX RANGE SCAN| ID_INDX |     1 |     3 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - access("ID"=5)
```

Above all the three cases, **index** is used.

**DECODE on the column:**

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM t  WHERE decode(ID, NULL, 3, 5) = 5;

        ID
----------
         1
         2
         3
         4
         5
         6
         7
         8
         9
        10

10 rows selected.


Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1601196873

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |     1 |     3 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| T    |     1 |     3 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter(DECODE(TO_CHAR("ID"),NULL,3,5)=5)
```

**NVL on the column:**

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM t  WHERE nvl(ID, 3) = 3;

        ID
----------
         3


Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1601196873

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |     1 |     3 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| T    |     1 |     3 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter(NVL("ID",3)=3)

SQL>
```

As expected, index is not used as you are applying a function on the column having a regular index. You need a function-based index.

So, you are right, you don't have to worry about index usage when you are not applying the function on the column, but on the parameter value.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer!